# Как лучше сверстать блоки разной высоты на Bootstrap?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Прошу прощения за мой дилетантский вопрос:

Есть макет сайта вот такого плана:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aylFw.jpg]

Все блоки на сайте размещены сеткой, у каждого блока высота равна или x, или 2x, или 3x, ширина тоже - y, или 2y.

Пробую сделать на Bootstrap, но, из-за высоты, бутстрап размещает 4-й блок не под 2-м, а под первым, с новой строки.
Пример: https://www.codeply.com/go/dwyEv5gprw

Подскажите, как решить данный вопрос?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это особенности 4-го Бутстрапа. Поэтому у Вас 2 варианта: либо просто подключить 3-й, и тогда всё заработает (только колонкам padding: 0 !important надо задать):

```css
.col-lg-4, .col-lg-8{
    padding: 0 !important;
}
p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.feature{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.height1{
  height: 150px;
}
.height2{
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section id="features">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height2">
              <p>1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>5</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>6</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>7</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>8</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>9</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>10</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Либо если по каким-то причинам нужен именно 4-й бутстрап, переопределите в стилях поведение row и col-

```css
.row {
  display: block !important;
}
.col-lg-4, .col-lg-8{
padding: 0 !important;
float: left !important;
}
p{
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
}
.feature{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.height1{
  height: 150px;
}
.height2{
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="features">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height2">
              <p>1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>5</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>6</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>7</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>8</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>9</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="feature height1">
              <p>10</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ! Подскажите, а какой вариант будет более целесообразен, учитывая, что в будущем верстка будет переноситься на Wordpress и чтобы пользователь мог сам добавлять блоки на свой выбор с одинарной или двойной высотой/шириной?

Comment: @VostrikovaVera, насчёт целесообразности не знаю, но очевидно, что 3-й бутстрап здесь использовать проще: фактически ничего не надо переопределять в стилях